# Are LLMs, in particular GPT3.5/4, better at interpreting XML or JSON for input?

Tags: structured-data, json, gpt-3.5-turbo

I understand that JSON is used as standard for structured output.

I have a requirement for structured input - for example a list of objects like chat messages / statements to analyze which have a natural sequence, and different participant IDs.

Is this structured input best provided to LLMs (particularly GPT3.5) as XML, JSON, CSV or something else?

Comment: XML is crazy verbose and eats tokens like there's no tomorrow. CSV is the most efficient, if your data is flat. JSON is a happy middle ground.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAi just announced they added a better JSON instruction mode to help developers structure inputs and prompts better.

Take a look [here](https://openai.com/blog/new-models-and-developer-products-announced-at-devday) and [here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/json-mode)

So maybe stick to JSON for Input and outputs as it seems to be the format of predilection for now.

Hope this helps !